# How to write "descriptions for arguments" in R when coding the wrapper functions?

Tags: r, function, wrapper

I have an R code to obtain a particular estimate, and there, I need to write the function description when giving the values to the arguments. (Please refer the attached document to get a clear picture of what I need, as an example)

My question is, how to write the code for this kind of a display, when calling my function?

[image]

Comment: RStudio pulls this from the relevant .Rd entry in `man/` folder of the source package. See `?rpareto` -- it's from there

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Actually, I'm writing my own package. For that I need to write the wrapper functions by popping out warnings and so on. There, how can I code for a second user to get help of the argument description?

Comment: Like in the image, n means, "number of observations". So "number of observations" is the description of the argument n. Without that description, a user do not know what value he should enter to obtain the result through that function. How do I popup that "description" to the next user? (How to code that to be displayed?)

Comment: If you're righting your own package (good thing to do), you might consider using `roxygen2`, perhaps using guidance from [R packages](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz), [Documentation](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/man.html). In that stead, if you add `#' @param n number of observations` immediately before the function declaration in the source (`.R`) file, then run something like `devtools::document("path/to/your/pkg")`, your `man/` page will contain what you need. (I don't know that RStudio pulls it dynamically, so changing your documentation might not see an immediate change here.)

Comment: Dang corrections ... *"If you're **writing** your own package"* ... (head hung low, face-palm).